# Where should I put files to be sent via send_file in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, asset-pipeline

Where am I supposed to put files to be served via send_file in Rails 3?

Suppose I'm serving a browser extension that may be updated once a month or two, should I put it in the asset pipeline? And how can I access it from the controller?
If I refer to it using `#{Rails.root}` it won't work in the production environment.
I don't want to have to change `config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header` every time I'll deploy on a different webserver, and I don't want to set `config.serve_static_assets = true` since this is a distortion of the development environment.

Comment: Does the file need to be protected from anonymous download? That's the usual use-case for send-file

Comment: Yes, there is a before_filter

Comment: Consider aws s3 for file storage as well

Answer (score 0):

You should put them in a directory outside of Public, otherwise they will be viewable by the browser directly without authentication.

I usually create a directory in Rails.root, something like

```
Rails.root
 - app
 - config
 - db
 - secure_files
```

So the files will be present in secure_files.